# Apply scrollpane if not webkit

Tags: jquery, browser, cross-browser, webkit, jscrollpane

I styled with CSS the scroll bar for webkit. For now it's only possible with webkit with plain CSS. For the rest for now it seems you can only use a jquery plugin, in this case I wish to use jscrollpane. I checked the following [tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-styling-scrollbars-to-match-your-ui-design/) and everything works except:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          if (!$.browser.webkit) {
              $('.container').jScrollPane();
          }
      });
```

It seems from jquery 1.9 `$.browser` is not supported anymore. I'm actually using jquery 1.10.2. I checked and they highly recommend to use feature detection from Modernizr. I have modernizr but I've read articles and still don't understand what I need to do. Therefore the effect I wish to create is that jscrollpane is applied only if the browser is not using webkit. Could somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

just check the `Modernizr.cssscrollbar` property.

this will populate the property:

```
Modernizr.addTest("cssscrollbar",function(){var a,b="#modernizr{overflow: scroll; width: 40px }#"+Modernizr._prefixes.join("scrollbar{width:0px} #modernizr::").split("#").slice(1).join("#")+"scrollbar{width:0px}";return Modernizr.testStyles(b,function(b){a="scrollWidth"in b&&b.scrollWidth==40}),a})
```

then you can use it

```
if (!Modernizr.cssscrollbar) {
  //activate plugin
}
```

Comment: This is used to style it or to redirect the browser into jscrollpane? at this moment I'm checking what you posted.

Comment: it is use to detect the feature

Comment: Thank you, where do you place the property to populate this? Where did you find this? I don't find this on the web... Another question is. Does this have the same functionality as $.browser? I see some CSS properties and I don't understand for what is this?

Comment: `$.browser` is an old standard, nowadays the suggested practice is to test for single browser features and react accordingly, rather than testing the browser's vendor/version

Comment: this is a custom Modernizr test (it supports user defined tests)

Comment: usage: load Modernizr `script`, on `document.ready` run the `addTest`, then do the `if` check and start the plugin if needed

Comment: I've tried the following and it does not work: On header I call Modernizr, on window.load I run the line you added on Modernizr. Then I inserted the the if and inserted a code to check if it works. Opened Firefox and nothing really happened. Did I miss something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38961/discussion-between-daniel-ramirez-escudero-and-david-fregoli)